# Calibrate Camera with only radial distortion

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to run camera calibration using opencv in python. I'm using:

```
cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

and it seems like it is working well for 5 distortion coefficients. However, I would like to try and run it without the tangential distortion and possibly with only 2 radial distortion coefficients. Is that possible?

Comment: do you only need lens correction (undistortion) or do you need all the camera intrinsics?

Comment: I need all the camera intrinsics + the lens correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

For no tangential distortion:

```
 ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None, 4,None,None,cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST,
                                                   criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 2e-16))
```

For only 2 radial distortion coefficients it seems like the documentation suggests using 4 instead of 5 for the number of coefficients. That does not seem to work. Instead I fix the k3 parameter:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None, 4,None,None,cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST+cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3,
                                                   criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 2e-16))
```

Answer (score 2):

[The relevant documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d):

> **distCoeffs** – Output vector of distortion coefficients [image: formula] of 4, 5, or 8 elements.
>
> **CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS** cameraMatrix contains valid initial
> values of fx, fy, cx, cy that are optimized further. Otherwise, (cx,
> cy) is initially set to the image center ( imageSize is used), and
> focal distances are computed in a least-squares fashion. Note, that if
> intrinsic parameters are known, there is no need to use this function
> just to estimate extrinsic parameters. Use solvePnP() instead.
>
> **CV_CALIB_FIX_K1,...,CV_CALIB_FIX_K6** The corresponding radial
> distortion coefficient is not changed during the optimization. If
> CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS is set, the coefficient from the supplied
> distCoeffs matrix is used. Otherwise, it is set to 0.
>
> **CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST** Tangential distortion coefficients [image: formula] are set to zeros and stay zero.

**IMPORTANT**: in Python, cv flags DON'T BEGIN WITH `CV_`. So I will remove them from now on.

---

What the documentation means is:

If you *already have* a camera matrix **AND** distortion coefficient vector, you can supply them to the calibration as an initial value and let it guess from there (using `CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS`). You can supply an initial distortion vector and make some components of it static (will always be the supplied value) with the  `CALIB_FIX_K1`,…,`CALIB_FIX_K6` flags.

**BUT:** if you set `CALIB_FIX_K1`, `CALIB_FIX_K2`, `CALIB_FIX_K3`, `CALIB_FIX_K4`, `CALIB_FIX_K5` or `CALIB_FIX_K6` without giving an initial estimate, **they will be set to zero**.

Note that the result distCoeffs vector will be: [`K1`, `K2`, `tangential1`, `tangential2`, `K3`]. OpenCV will give you K4, K5 or K6 only if you explicitly ask for it with `CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL`.

So, if you want no tangential distortion factors and only two radial distortion factors, you can supply `flags=CALIB_FIX_K3 + CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST`. You don't need `distCoeffs` or just pass it  as `distCoeffs=None`.

```
success, mtx, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        objectPoints, imagePoints, (width, height),
        flags=CALIB_FIX_K3 + CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST)

print(distCoeffs)
```

This will result in a distortion vector like this:

`[ 0.10509459 -0.31389323  0.          0.          0.     ]`